# Как в модуле drupal использовать альтернативную тему

Tags: drupal, themes, модули

Пишу модуль для Drupal 7.

На странице site.ru   - Основная тема

На странице site.ru/other  - Должна быть другая тема

Что читать, что использовать, чтобы осуществить данную задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вам модуль? Для этого есть тема, в которой вы и настраиваете свой дизайн.
Если тема основной страницы и других достаточно сильно отличается, то можно использовать `template suggestions`:

- для главной страницы определить файл `page--front.tpl.php`,
- для всех остальных - `page.tpl.php`.

[Полный список доступных шаблонов](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

После добавления новых шаблонов обязательно очистите кэш Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Модуль позволяет использовать разные темы в зависимости от многих параметров https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey